# Ionic 5: Cannot find name 'angular'

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm getting that error when I'm trying to make a simple foreach, am I missing any importation?

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavParams} from '@ionic/angular';
import {AuthService} from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-modal',
templateUrl: './edit-modal.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-modal.page.scss'],
})

 especialidadEdit(especialidad) {
    // tslint:disable-next-line:only-arrow-functions
        angular.forEach(especialidad, function(value, key) {
        console.log(key + ': ' + value);
    });
}
```

Comment: Paste full .ts code

Comment: angular.forEach relates to AngularJS, not Angular. From a pure programming perspective angular isn't defined or imported anywhere so yea, it's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling `angular.forEach` - angular is not a global, nor is it imported, hence the error "Cannot find angular".

Without knowing the structure of `especialidad`, guessing you are trying to do something like this:

```
especialidad.forEach(item => {
  console.log(item);
})
```

Answer (score 1):

angular.foreach is deprecated in the angular 1.x version, From version 2 and up you can just use javascript syntax.

Did not test it but should be like this. And also fixed your linting issue:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {ModalController, NavParams} from '@ionic/angular';
import {AuthService} from '../../../services/auth.service';

@Component({
selector: 'app-edit-modal',
templateUrl: './edit-modal.page.html',
styleUrls: ['./edit-modal.page.scss'],
})

 especialidadEdit(especialidad) {
    especialidad.forEach((value, index) => {
        console.log(index + ': ' + value);
    });
}
```